SvelteKit Router Not Generating Routes After Build
I am currently working on a mini web app and trying to deploy it to a VM. Everything works fine via npm run dev, but routes do not work when running VS Code live server on the dist after npm run build or npx serve dist in the root directory.
The only way I can get any routes besides the root to work is via npx serve dist --single.
I also want to note that specific route directories are not generated in the dist folder after npm run build. Here is my current directory structure under src.
src
├── app.d.ts
├── app.html
├── globals.css
├── lib
│   └── components
│       ├── Image.svelte
│       ├── Light.svelte
│       └── ThreeJSWindow.svelte
└── routes
    ├── +layout.svelte
    ├── +page.svelte
    ├── tree
    │   └── +page.svelte
    └── v1
        └── +page.svelte

No directories are generated in dist corresponding to the /tree or /v1 routes.
My main goal is to deploy this to a VM as a static html server using nginx without having to configure this as a node server. I tried doing that and could not get it working either.
I figure if I cannot run this app via live server in the dist directory, I should not try deploying it yet.
I originally assumed that this was an issue with my svelte.config.js file, but nothing has worked so far:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'dist', 
      assets: 'dist',
      fallback: 'index.html', 
    }),
    paths: {
      base: '', 
    },
    prerender: {
      entries: ['*'],  
    },
  },
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
};

export default config;


No directories are generated in dist corresponding to the /tree or /v1 routes. Do you have links in your HTML code that leads to these pages somehow from your start page? SvelteKit will not look at your directory structure, but crawl the links it can find from the start page, and the pages they lead to, etc.

And you have set the prerender option to true in your root +layout.svelte file? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#usage

Ok, thank you for the quick responses! I think the root of the issue comes from my use of Tailwind and Javascript options in my root +page.svelte file. Instead of statically typing in all of my elements, I am using text object lists and mapping over them via Tailwind styling.
When I insert the links statically, the routes work, which I may just do in this particular case. If I decided to leave my links / text as text objects, how could I make sure their routes are built?

It sounds like your tailwind solution only works when the user has client-side JS enabled in their web browser. That sounds like a bad solution; webpages should function without client-side JS. So the proper solution is to not use something that only works if client-side JS is enabled. But you can hardcore these links in your HTML code, and then remove them using client-side JS in onMount(). Just let me know if you need some sample code.
